# Friedman test for a repeated measures experiment with replicates

Tags: r, repeated-measures, group-differences, friedman-test

(Please see example with reproducible data at the end)
I have a data file with the results of an exercise performed 16 times
with each of 2 control devices by 3 subjects. I measured the task
completion time to accomplish the exercise (TCT). There are 2
different exercises.
The table has thus 4 variables:
S (subject, S1 to S3); CTL (control interface, EM or F); Type of
exercise (Type, 1 or 2)
and task completion time (TCT).

I have already performed a detailed analysis with boxplots to compare
between control interfaces
for each subject and exercise type. But I also would like an overall
test to report whether there are
significant overall differences among subjects and between control systems.
Data are not normal and variances are not homogeneous. I cannot find
any suited transformation.
Also, the observations are not independent. I've used a Friedman test
but it is the first time
I use it and would like to make sure I'm doing it right. In particular
because I reformat the data set to fulfill the requirement "exactly
one observation in y for each combination of levels of groups and
blocks" of function friedman.test()

**1. Test differences among subjects.**
I reformat the data set by creating a variable trial that goes from 1 to 64
for each subject, so the new table all2FDS has simply 3 variables:
trial, S and TCT
I use:

```
friedman.test(TCT ~ S | trial,data = all2FDS)
```

and get:

```
  Friedman rank sum test  
  data:  TCT and S and trial  
  Friedman chi-squared = 27.594, df = 2, p-value = 1.019e-06
```

**2. Test differences between control sytems.**
I reformat the data set by creating a variable trial that goes from 1 to 96
for each control system, so the new table all2FDCTL has simply 3
variables: trial, CTL and TCT
I use:

```
friedman.test(TCT ~ CTL | trial,data = all2FDCTL)
```

and get:

```
  Friedman rank sum test  
  data:  TCT and CTL and trial  
  Friedman chi-squared = 1.0417, df = 1, p-value = 0.3074
```

**Am I using friedman.test() correctly?**

In order to facilitate the answers, I include here what I think would
be an equivalent reproducible example:

Using friedman.test examples: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/muStat/docs/mu.kruskal.test

```
treatments <- factor(rep(c("Trt1", "Trt2", "Trt3"), each=4))  
people <- factor(rep(c("Subj1", "Subj2", "Subj3", "Subj4"), 3))  
y <- c(0.73,0.76,0.46,0.85,0.48,0.78,0.87,0.22,0.51,0.03,0.39,0.44)  
midata <- data.frame(treatments,people,y)  
midata[1:10,]
```

I would do as follows:

```
**Test among treatments**  
friedman.test(y ~ treatments|people,data=midata)  
**Test among subjects**  
friedman.test(y ~ people|treatments,data=midata)
```

The difference with my dataset is that I have "trials" instead of "treatments".

Comment: This sounds like survival analysis, is there a reason you aren't using that? Do you have any censoring?

Comment: In what way does this sound like survival analysis?